# /usr/include/netinet/in.h:138: note: candidates are: in_addr& in_addr::operator=(const in_addr&)

Tags: tcp, client-server

I wrote a simple TCP/IP network applications (server and client). In the code of client app, I did like this and then build with **'g++ -o client client.cpp'** under Linux.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    struct sockaddr_in server_addr;
    struct hostent* host;

    ....
    memset(&server_addr, 0, sizeof(server_addr));
    server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server_addr.sin_port = htons(nPort);
    server_addr.sin_addr = *((struct in_ddr*)host->h_addr); /*It complains as below while building*/
    ....
}
```

client.cpp: In function 'int main(int, char**)':
client.cpp:56: error: no match for 'operator=' in 'server_addr.sockaddr_in::sin_addr = *(in_ddr*)(* host->hostent::h_addr_list)'
/usr/include/netinet/in.h:138: note: candidates are: in_addr& in_addr::operator=(const in_addr&)
*** Error code 1
clearmake: Error: Build script failed for "client"

what's going on with my implementaion?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to set an address list as a single address. You'll want to use brackets to refer to the address you want. `host->h_addr_list[0]`

At least that is what I am getting from your error.

[**Reference sources**](http://www.cs.tufts.edu/comp/112/examples/Names_and_Numbers/gethostbyname.c)